# Testing performance of C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, performance, profiling

What free tools could I use to test the performance of C++ code in Linux? Basically I want to identify the bottleneck of the code and improve on the performance. My application mainly involves computational code using the data from the network. So I would like to improve the speed of execution of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean you need good tool for profiling? OProfile perhaps, valgrind-tools?

Comment: Is the code computation-intensive (CPU), disk-I/O intensive, network I/O intensive, memory consuming, multi-threaded, etc? Knowing some initial directions will help you find a more suitable tool.

Comment: do you want to time the execution or analyse the working of the code ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For typical performance benchmarking this is what i use.

- gprof/oprofile - for CPU intensive profiling of your code.
- netstat/ethereal - for network statistics
- iostat/sar - for I/O
- vmstat - for memory
- mpstat/sar - for cpu usage

Now u can isolate the problems based on the output of these tools.

For eg:- if I/O is constant and within limits u can eliminate I/O as a problem.
If CPU usage is heavy as shown my mpstat then get into profiling using gprof/oprofile.

Without the use of all of them together for different runs, its difficult to identify the bottleneck.

Note: U can write a script to run all of them together and store the results in designated folders for each run.

Comment: +1 for mentioning good tools.  +valgrind for extremely CPU/cache intensive tasks.  For a quick start, it's worth checking the ratio of CPU to elapsed time while the program's working - can see that in top.  If it's pretty idle then you need to improve your network - consider alternative ways of packing/compressing the data.  If the CPUs pegged, use `gprof` or whatever to describe which functions are taking the time, or introduce your own timers (boost has high-res timing functions you can use) to measure how long it takes particular parts of your processing to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **valgrind** for

- cpu usage, callgrind submodule (source line granularity)
- memory leaks
- building call graphs
- some advanced issues like finding problems in multithread locking mechanism

The callgrind output can be visually displayed via KCacheGrind.

Answer (score 1):

By far the best profiler for Linux that I know of is [Zoom](http://rotateright.com). Although it's a commercial product it's not too expensive and you can get a free 30 day evaluation licence on request

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul says, give [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/) a try.

Personally, I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), which works for [these reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343), and Zoom approximates it. It is a technique that [some programmers have independently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118).

I'm also told OProfile can do it, but you have to know what you need to make it do.