# Free Profiler for execution analysis

Tags: visual-studio, profiling, performance

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition and I don't have the "Analyze" menu to profile the execution of my application. Does anyone know any good/free tool which can be used instead of the original profiler of VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many free profilers; but using the trial version of [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [red-gate ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) convinced me that getting a good tool requires money.

Comment: What are you looking for? Pretty UI? Lots and lots of statistics? or *results*? [If you're after results, try this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) And don't take my word for it - check the last paragraph [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832642/when-is-optimization-premature/4832698#4832698).

Answer (score 0):

[EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/) has a free version.

Answer (score 0):

[Tips for optimizing C#/.NET programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118)
The interesting thing about this is there's no formal, statistical, or practical sense in which any profiling tool will do a better job, or at least not that I've heard.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the free [Microsoft CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en).

Comment: Can this be used for .Net 3.5? In the link it says Framework 2.0

Comment: @DeveloperInToronto: yes it can.

Comment: Why the downvote? Also downvoting without a comment is a jerk move.