# ASP.net profiling and performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, profiling

I check my WebApp with dotTrace to understand some performance issues. In the example below, 67,3% of the time is used by KernelBase. Do you have any idea why this process is time consuming and how to solution or understand it ? I dont known if the issue is with IIS, resources (IO, CPU, RAM) or ASP.net.

[dotTrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhYBQ.png)

Comment: You're looking at the "hot path", which is only useful if your bottleneck is on it. More likely, it is not. There's a method that's not only simple and free, but more effective. Check the last paragraph of [*this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4832698/23771).

Comment: It is possible this time to be compile time ? Its looks like compile...

Comment: Compile ? JIT compilation ?