# can't start visual studio profiler

Tags: visual-studio, profiler, vsperfmon

I have VS 2010 Ultimate. I have created empty win32 console solution and replaced it's cpp file with http://pastebin.com/EQJKJK6T I tried to perform CPU Sampling profiling. But for some reason I get the following messages

MessageBox:

> Could not launch 'path to exe file'. Previous attempt to profile the
>   application finished unsuccessfully. Please restart the application.

Output window:

> ```
> Profiling started.
> Warning VSP2355: Some Windows counters will not be collected.  Without this data, some performance rules may not fire.
> Profiling process ID 4368 (test).
> Process ID 4368 has exited.
> Data written to e:\projects\test\test101224.vsp.
> Profiling finished.
> PRF0025: No data was collected. 
> Profiling complete.
> ```

Comment: there is a mistake in the code (new version http://pastebin.com/anXMPRZu) but this does not resolve problem with the profiling

Comment: hmm, this I uninstalled vmware player and now everything is ok

Comment: Have you considered [this method of finding what to optimize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, yet bizarrely it only affected one Visual Studio solution.  Using the profiler with another Visual Studio solution worked fine.

I tried:

- [disabling Symantec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068400/could-not-launch-xxx-exe-previous-attempt-to-profile-the-application-finished-u#6841658)
- uninstalling VMware Player (as mentioned above)

but neither worked.

In the end I [amended the registry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85ebadf5-704e-4d1a-844a-be62a904e65a/functionality-needed-by-the-profiler-has-been-intercepted-by-another-application?forum=vstsprofiler), setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysPlant\Start` to `4` and rebooted, it then started working.