# Could not launch xxx.exe. Previous attempt to profile the application finished unsuccessfully. Please restart the application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling, profiler

I am facing an error message while profiling a c# console application in VS 2010 (using CPU Sampling method of profiling). When I click on Start Profiling: following error message is displayed:

"Could not launch D:\xxx\yyy\zzz.exe. Previous attempt to profile the application finished unsuccessfully. Please restart the application."

I have tried to profile a new Console Application, but I face the same error message.

What can be the reason for this error? Do I need to configure something? Please help!!!

Comment: While you're fooling around with that, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 3):

This is due to anti virus protection on your system. check the following link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsprofiler/thread/85ebadf5-704e-4d1a-844a-be62a904e65a