# Could not launch xxx.exe. Previous attempt to profile the application finished unsuccessfully. Please restart the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I'm having the exact same problem as outlined in this post:

[Could not launch xxx.exe. Previous attempt to profile the application finished unsuccessfully. Please restart the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068400/could-not-launch-xxx-exe-previous-attempt-to-profile-the-application-finished-un/7309261#7309261)

All the Profiling methods give the same error on my system.  The type of project I'm trying to profile is XNA/C#.

The provided solution to that problem is the only solution I can find using Google but it does not apply to me as I do not have Symantec anti-virus.  Also, there are no instances of the SysPlant registry key (as mentioned in the above link) on my system.  I have tried disabling all anti-malware and anti-virus software on my system but still get the error. Does anyone else have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, yet bizarrely it only affected one Visual Studio solution.  Using the profiler with another Visual Studio solution worked fine.

I tried:

- [disabling Symantec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068400/could-not-launch-xxx-exe-previous-attempt-to-profile-the-application-finished-u#6841658)
- [uninstalling VMware Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524903/cant-start-visual-studio-profiler)

but neither worked.

In the end I [amended the registry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85ebadf5-704e-4d1a-844a-be62a904e65a/functionality-needed-by-the-profiler-has-been-intercepted-by-another-application?forum=vstsprofiler), setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysPlant\Start` to `4` and rebooted, it then started working.