# C++ run timing IDE perhaps?

Tags: c++, performance

is there an IDE or perhaps a piece of software that could time my C++ programs? I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 so if there's a functionality to help with that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a *profiler*; make a quick search in SO, there are several suggestions about them.

Comment: What edition of VS2010?  It affects the answer.

Comment: While you're getting used to the idea of a profiler, you might try [this very simple method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a Profiler. There are plenty of options out there, but start with what you have natively in VS - please read [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

Taken from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=291294)

> Determining the speed of a particular
>   operation is often known as profiling.
>   The term "profiling" can also be used
>   when other information about an
>   operation's profile is queried -- such
>   as the number of calls to a function.

And, as always, MSDN is your friend with [Analyzing Application Performance by Using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx)

Comment: Note that the VS profiler is only available in Premium and Ultimate SKUs.  If you're using Pro or Express and do not have access to the higher SKUs, third party profilers are also available (check out a few of them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools).