# Are there any third-party profiling tools for C# in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, profiling

I'm looking for a tool to tell me how long my code takes to run.  Something that would be the equivalent of recording the `DateTime.Now` before and after each line of code in my program, then displaying the difference between the two times for each line (after my program finishes running).

For instance, if I have a program that calls four methods in its main, I want to know (after running this tool) how long each of those methods takes to run, and then if I stepped into each method, I'd want to know how long each line in there takes to run, and so on.

Do these tools exists?  Of course I'd prefer a free one, but if all that exist are professional tools then please mention those as well.

**edit:** it appears these tools are called Profiling tools.  Thanks, this will definitely help me in my search.  Unfortunately, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, so I believe the Microsoft profiling tool is out of my grasp.  Any good third-party profiling tools?

Comment: Re: DateTime.Now - look into Stopwatch class :) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: If you just want to measure, that's one thing. If you want to locate your time-drains so you can fix them to gain speed, there's a [very simple effective technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273)**

> The **CLR Profiler** includes a number of
>   very useful views of the allocation
>   profile, including a histogram of
>   allocated types, allocation and call
>   graphs, **a time line** showing GCs of
>   various generations and the resulting
>   state of the managed heap after those
>   collections, and a call tree showing
>   per-method allocations and assembly
>   loads.

And even more **[profilers and tools can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336818)**...

More about profiling [on the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: For [another viewpoint...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Profiler tool that come with VS it shows this to you very well. Only one down side is that I think it only comes with Ultimate. :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [performance profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)? It tells you how long each function takes.

Answer (score 0):

I like dotTrace, it's by the same guys that make Resharper: [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). There's a free trial, and if you don't have access to the built-in VS2010 profiler, it does a good job.

Comment: The product name is ANTS. Redgate are the company.