# Profiler tool in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, profiler

Does anyone know a debug tool for VS2008 that can be used to see what methods are executing and how long it takes?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/).  Free, very quick and easy to set up, intuitive and informative user interface.

Comment: It did not work for me. I got the error 10:17:25 AM: Failed to start Silverlight policy server at port 943: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
10:17:27 AM: Failed to start Profiler command-module at port 4515: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Answer (score 1):

I know of two free profilers:

AQTime (Smart Bear): http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/
And the one that is built into SharpDevelop: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/download/

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a measurement tool?
or
Do you want to find the lines of your code that you should fix to make it run faster?

They are no way the same thing.

Plenty of people have discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118).
It's not a tool you install and use, with a glamorous UI.
It's a simple [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) for using your IDE to quickly pinpoint the line(s) to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in the profiling tools that are built into Visual Studio 2008 if you have the Developer or Suite editions. See: [Analyzing Application Performance using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

AMD's [CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools/codeanalyst/pages/default.aspx) is free and can give you very usable results though the interface can be a bit confusing (in particular how to get callstacks), but it's worth devoting a bit of time to getting to know it.  It integrates well into VisualStudio too