# profiling in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling

It looks as though the profiling tools are only available in the Premium and Ultimate editions of Visual Studio 2010.

Is there a reasonable alternative which is free?

Comment: While you're waiting, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118).

Answer (score 17):

You can download the standalone profiling tools here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23205

Follow the instructions here for how to run them via command-line. The guide is for 2008, you just need to replace Visual Studio 9.0 with Visual Studio 10.0 anywhere it is mentioned:

http://codeka.com/blogs/index.php/2009/03/21/got-visual-studio-2008-professional-want

Comment: The MS Link appears to have died on us. I can still find the 2008 and 2015 standalone profilers, but 2010 seems to have disappeared from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Good news is that, [profiling tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/) are in the FREE Community edition of Visual Studio 2015 (and of course the Professional and Enterprise editions as well).

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>