# RichTextBox horrible performance in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I realize a program which basically imports data. The log of the import is built with a `StringBuilder`, and then printed in a `RichTextBox`, programmaticaly, in a new `Window`.

I searched how to hightlight specific words and how to put in bold lines containing specific characters.

For example, part of my log looks like this :

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't found a "magic solution" in WPF for this, so I made a code which is not very optimized / proper. This is my code :

```
TextRange tr;
foreach(var line in finalText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentEnd, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

    foreach (var word in line.Split(' '))
    {
        tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentEnd, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Text = word + ' ';

        if (line.IndexOf("====", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
        }
        else if (line.IndexOf("Statut", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)14);
        }
        else if (line.IndexOf("Fin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)14);
        }
        else
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)12);
        }

        if (word.IndexOf("Succès", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 || word.IndexOf("Succes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
        }
        else if (word.IndexOf("Erreur", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        }
        else if (word.IndexOf("Info", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkOrange);
        }
        else if (word.IndexOf("Modif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkBlue);
        }
        else
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        }
    }
    tr.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

*Note* : `finalText` is the `String` representing the log and `rtb` is the RichTextBox.

As you can see when a entire line needs to be in bold, I re-apply the property to each word because I need a new `TextRange` for each new word, in order to change the color.

The problem is that with only a few lines of log (let's say `50 lines`), I found my code to be very slow : this single piece of code takes up to `3 seconds` to complete. The import itself (opening files, analyzing, making operations in database on a lot of data) does not take such time.

Any hint to reduce this time ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use a profiling tool to find out which parts of your program are actually causing the slow down.  It should break down each function by the amount of time that the CPU spend in each.  That will give you the best idea of where you should spend your time optimizing.  It will also give you a REAL number to compare results to so that you know if your changes are actually making a difference.  There is some build in profiling support in Visual Studio under the "Analyze" menu.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm sure this is this piece of code (I measured it with `StopWatch`). But if I can isolate even more, can you tell me which profiling tool I should use for example ?

Comment: A profiler will tell you specifically if it's the string concatination, all the calls to ApplyPropertyValue, or even the string.Split call that is slowing you down.  I'd start with the profiler built in to Visual Studio.

Comment: This link should give you a good idea of how to use the profiler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: @BradleyUffner Unfortunatly, according to this link ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ), I can't use the profiler. I only have the 2010 Profesionnal version. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Check out this option to run it stand alone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852417/profiling-in-visual-studio-2010-professional

Comment: Try setting the Visibility property to Hidden while this code runs.

Comment: @HansPassant It has no effect.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've done it, but I can't understand the generated files. The functions are just numbers and the files are too big.

Comment: Try this one https://code.google.com/p/slimtune/

Comment: @BradleyUffner It works; but I don't see where I can collect interesting data. The only thing I found is that : http://puu.sh/ho3tz/d90c18ea9b.png