# Profiler show incorrect elapsed time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, profiler

I am using the profiler tool coming with VS2015 (Debug -> Profiler -> Start Diagnostics Tools Without Debugging...)

I am getting the diagnostic results but there are not really clear to me.

1. The Current Function shows 80 sec. but the total of the called functions inside the current function is about 42 sec.

[image]

2. The current function shows 29 sec. but the total of the called functions inside the current function is about 58 sec.

[image]

I was expecting that the total time of the called functions will be equal to the time of the current function.

Why are they different?
To which value should I refer to?

Comment: The first case is obvious enough, don't profile code that displays a dialog like MsgBox.  Which takes lots of time but no cycles.

Comment: Have you tried [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474118/23771)?