# Attaching Visual Studio debugger causes high CPU usage and UI thread locks

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, profiling

I have a WPF app that does some async networking (negotiation over 100 sockets in parallel). If I launch app with VS debugger attached and start networking code my CPU usage jumps to 60% (shared between VS, VS debugger and vshost processes) and UI becomes very unresponsive with constant freezes up to 3 seconds. The same happens when I attach a debugger to already running process. Under normal conditions it uses 1-3% CPU and UI is smooth.

VS profiler in "CPU usage" mode shows that CPU is used by [External code]

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Look in the Output window to see what is going on, crystal ball says that you see a *lot* of messages.  They are not cheap.

Comment: Indeed I have a lot of "Exception thrown" messages. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown at about 30/second rate but this is normal in my use case, all of them are caught.

Comment: Ok looks like slowdown is indeed caused by a large exception rate. I've tried to remove my networking code and replace it with a single exception throw and I still got unresponsive UI. I've also disabled first chance exceptions in the output window but it didn't fix the problem. Is there some option for debugger to stop collecting first chance exceptions?

Comment: 30 per second is not so likely to be the easy explanation.  Right-click the Output window and untick "Exception messages" to cut down on the overhead.  Using a profiler next would be wise.

Comment: Do you mean if your WPF app doesn't do any Async networking, the debugger will not cause high CPU? Is this Async networking project also in the same solution with the WPF app and you are running them at the same time?

Comment: Yes while app is not running any jobs it is smooth. I've already found out that I can throw away networking code and replace it with an exception throw and still get a slowdown effect. So essentially I have a loop that launches async tasks that wait a bit and then throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you just throw the Exception, how did you really handle this Exception?

For example, if the client sends the requests to the server side, and server side gives the responses to the client, but your client can't really handle the response with some Exceptions, I think it would impact your UI process which may have high CPU usage or others.

So the real cause is that what the Exception is and how to really resolve/handle this Exception.

To avoid seeing that messages, right-click on the output window and uncheck "Exception Messages" is a workaround, but find the real reason and resolve it would be a better solution.

Comment: First of all, my app works perfectly fine with no debugger attached. I work with pretty unreliable network and servers so my policy on handling network exceptions is to silently log them and retry operation. Most of them are TimeoutException and SocketException. As I already pointed out, hiding exceptions from output window doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you disable the option "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" in your WPF project property? It seems that you use the VS profiler tool, do you use this CPU tool? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/02/28/new-cpu-usage-tool-in-the-performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013/, do you get any items under the  [External code] tree?

Comment: As I already pointed out in my post >> VS profiler in "CPU usage" mode shows that CPU is used by [External code]