# .Net Profiler/Performance tuning

Tags: performance, profiler

This could be a very basic question. But I am not anywhere. In most of the answers i have seen profiler. e.g. creating 9000 object requires 10 sec. I can do that using code. But wondering if there is a tool that can do the job for me?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things:

1. Measuring execution time
2. Performance tuning

They are not the same, no matter what you might think or be told.
Speed comes from (2). (1) only tells the result.

If you are trying to do (2) performance tuning, you need to know precisely *what activity* accounts for a large fraction of time you could avoid spending, not precisely *how much* time is spent by something you can't tell if you need or not.
In other words, it's not a *measuring* problem; it's a *debugging* problem.

Here is [*one simple way to do it*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474118/23771).